# How to add a 'data-*' attribute when using Object.assign to create an html element

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```js
let item = Object.assign(document.createElement('img'), {
    className: 'carouselItem',
    src: `/public/leerlingen/${data.item}`,
    loading: 'eager',
});
item.setAttribute('data-showtime', data.duration)
```

I want to set a data attribute in the object assign, instead of separately.
I tried `dataset: { showtime: data.duration }`, but that results in the following typeerror
TypeError: setting getter-only property "dataset"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but you could try `"data-showtime": data.duration`

Comment: I'm actually surprised that using `Object.assign()` works to create DOM elements.

Comment: Did you try this ? `let item = Object.assign(document.createElement('img'), {
    className: 'carouselItem',
    src: `/public/leerlingen/${data.item}`,
    loading: 'eager',
 'data-showtime': data.duration
});`

Comment: I did, and while it did not error out, it also doesn't add the showtime data attr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this might be a nicer way to do this, if all you want is to set attributes to the image element.

```js
const imageRef = document.createElement('img');

Object.entries({
    className: 'carouselItem',
    src: `/public/leerlingen/${data.item}`,
    loading: 'eager',
    'data-showtime': data.duration
}).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    imageRef.setAttribute(key, value);
});
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you very much. Didn't know you could do it with Object.entries